# Linux Text Extraction GREP

Tags: grep, ubuntu-server, teamspeak

I am running a Teamspeak 3 server on a Ubuntu server and I would like to fetch the clients currently connected using a script.

The script currently outputs this from the Teamspeak Server Query:

```
clid=1 cid=11 client_database_id=161 client_nickname=Music client_type=1|clid=3 cid=11 client_database_id=153 client_nickname=Music\sBot client_type=0|clid=5 cid=1 client_database_id=68 client_nickname=Unknown\sfrom\s127.0.0.1:52537 client_type=1|clid=12 cid=11 client_database_id=3 client_nickname=FriendlyMan client_type=0|clid=16 cid=11 client_database_id=161 client_nickname=Windows\s10\sUser client_type=0|clid=20 cid=11 client_database_id=225 client_nickname=3C2J0N47H4N client_type=0
```

How can I extract the nicknames from this mess? 
More Specifically only the ones that contain "client_type=0".

Played around with GREP (grep -E -o 'client_nickname=\w+'), close to what I want.

```
client_nickname=Music
client_nickname=Music
client_nickname=Unknown
client_nickname=FriendlyMan
client_nickname=Windows
client_nickname=3C2J0N47H4N
```

Desired Output:

```
Music Bot,FriendlyMan,Windows 10 User,3C2J0N47H4N
```

Comment: Using "grep -E -o 'client_nickname=\w+'" I was almost able to get what I wanted but this fails for clients with spaces in their names.

Comment: What is the output you want?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that. I want a list of all of the clients nicknames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our input consists of a single line:

```
$ cat file
clid=1 cid=11 client_database_id=161 client_nickname=Music client_type=1|clid=3 cid=11 client_database_id=153 client_nickname=Music\sBot client_type=0|clid=5 cid=1 client_database_id=68 client_nickname=Unknown\sfrom\s127.0.0.1:52537 client_type=1|clid=12 cid=11 client_database_id=3 client_nickname=FriendlyMan client_type=0|clid=16 cid=11 client_database_id=161 client_nickname=Windows\s10\sUser client_type=0|clid=20 cid=11 client_database_id=225 client_nickname=3C2J0N47H4N client_type=0
```

#### Using grep + sed

Here is one approach that starts with grep and then uses sed to cleanup to the final format:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=client_nickname=)[^=]+(?=client_type=0)' file | sed -nE 's/\\s/ /g; H;1h; ${x; s/ *\n/,/g;p}'
Music Bot,FriendlyMan,Windows 10 User,3C2J0N47H4N
```

#### Using awk

Here is another approach that just uses awk:

```
$ awk -F'[= ]' '/client_type=0/{gsub(/\\s/, " ", $8); printf (f?",":"")$8; f=1} END{print ""}' RS='|' file
Music Bot,FriendlyMan,Windows 10 User,3C2J0N47H4N
```

The awk code uses `|` as the record separator and awk reads in one record at a time.  Each record is divided into fields with the field separator being either a space or an equal sign.  If the record contains the text `client_type=0`, then we replace all occurrences of `\s` in field 8 with space and then print the resulting field 8.

#### Using bash

```
#!/bin/bash
sep=
( cat file; echo "|"; ) | while read -r -d\| clid cid db name type misc
do
    [ "$type" = "client_type=0" ] || continue
    name=${name//\\s/ }
    printf "%s%s" "$sep" "${name#client_nickname=}"
    sep=,
done
echo ""
```

This produces the output:

```
Music Bot,FriendlyMan,Windows 10 User,3C2J0N47H4N
```

Comment: Wow that's complicated... Too advanced for me anyways. It Works!

Comment: I should start playing around with these text manipulators, they come in handy alot.

Comment: @CR33P1N3V1L Yes, both `sed` and `awk` come in quite handy.

Comment: I ran into a problem with the awk approach. The first users name was replaced with "type". I had that user re-log and it fixed it. I tried the grep + sed approach while the awk was having that glitch and it worked fine. Using the grep + sed for now.

Comment: @CR33P1N3V1L I'm glad `grep`+`sed` is working for you.  If you show me the input that confused the `awk` code, I'll see what I can do with it.